# Why my destructor shows that pointer being freed was not allocated c++

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, malloc

I want to implement 2 array addition, but when a destructor to the class SList

```
void operator+(SList list2) {
        int totalLen = this->len + list2.len;
        char** temp = new char* [totalLen];
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            temp[i] = this->list[i];
        }
        for(int i = len, j = 0; i < totalLen; i++, j++) {
            temp[i] = list2.get(j);
        }
        delete[] this->list;
        this->list = temp;
        this->len = totalLen;
        cout << len << endl << endl;
    }
```

Here are the get method that just return the dynamic array of char:

```
char* get(int i) {
        if (i >= len) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return list[i];
        }
    }
```

here are my class SList private variables:

```
private:
    char** list;
    int len;
    char* generateString(){
        char* str;
        int n = rand() % 20 + 1;
        str = new char[n + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            str[i] = 'a' + rand()%26;
        }
        str[n] = '\0';
        return str;
    };
```

```
~SList() {
        delete[] list;
    }
```

It always shows malloc error on the destructor.

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x105007410: pointer being freed was not allocated
malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Please help! I have carefully checked my delete method on the dynamic allocated array, but it always shows this error.

I have tried to check other delete from the other function, but none of them make the same malloc error. I have tried to commented the destructor method and everything work fine. But i really need to have destructor method here. I hope someone with more expertise on c++ can help me fix this malloc error and gave an explanation on which part i made a mistake.

Comment: This code is a disaster waiting to happen.  How do you allocate `list` originally?  Remember that `delete[] list` will not delete all the things those `list` entries point to.  Why are you not using `std::string` and `std::vector` or `std::list`?

Comment: What happens if `SList` is copied or assigned using the compiler generated default constructors or operators?

Comment: There is a number of faults in code shown which may cause this, but code that actually would cause this behaviour isn't shown at all. Minimal working example, please.

Comment: `void operator+(SList list2)` -- `operator +` should be returning a brand new `SList` that is the result of adding `this`'s `Slist` to `list2`.  It shouldn't be returning `void`.  The second thing is that `list2` should be passed by `const reference`, not by value.  Putting that all together, the function signature should be `SList operator + (const SList& list2)`.  Then it would make sense to have an `operator +=` that returns a reference to `this`, and then `operator +` could be implemented in terms of `operator +=` in one line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless what are other details of implementation, the destructor is not correct while you're using a data structure known as a "[ragged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20a%20jagged,edges%20when%20visualized%20as%20output.)", i.e. `list` is a pointer to an array of pointers. `delete[]` would free the pointer array, but not `char` arrays pointed by its elements. You have to do something like this:

```
~SList() {
    if(!list) return;   // if we cannot guarantee that list isn't 
                        // nullptr we have to check it, 
                        // or result of list[i] would be undefined. 
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        delete[] list[i];
    delete[] list;
}
```

and you have to make sure that any of those pointers is either initialized by `new` expression or is equal `nullptr`.. It doesn't happen on its own. You have to make sure during construction and all operations. You didn't show any. Look for faults there.

The method `get()` is a disaster waiting to happen and  is ill-formed, i.e. it doesn't  follow C++ rules. The string literal `""` returns  `const char*`, always the same one and the statement `return "";` is incorrect - some compilers only warn about it though. It cannot be deallocated by `delete`.

```
char* get(int i) {
    if (i >= len) {
        return nullptr;  // "" - is not safe
    } else {
        return list[i];
    }
}
```

Deleting a `nullptr` is a safe no-op. Deleting something that was't returned by `new` is a disaster.

The addition operator is taking `list2` by value, which means that proper copy operations have to be implemented. You didn't show them either. Default implementation would just copy a pointer and destruction of local copy would deallocate memory used by original via `~SList()` above. The operator have to return resulting object and should not modify one pointed by `this`. You had implemented an `operator+=`. The way you did it, it would work  as

```
 a+b;  // a now contains result of concatenation.
```

It's simply weird to use. Proper operator would be

```
SList operator+(SList& list2);
```

In general, an object that deals with ownership  of some resource, dynamic memory in our case, have to implement certain set of special member functions:

```
 ~SList();
 SList(const SList& other);
 SList(SList&& other); // move copy, source is a temporal.
 SList& operator=(const SList& other);
 SList& operator=(SList&& other); // move assignment
```

If that is done right, you can safely do the `c = a + b;` assignment.

Note that if you pass argument by reference you have to take in account that arguments of assigning operators aren't referencing the object pointed by `this` and act accordingly if they are. Otherwise you would destroy it and loose original data. On other hand copying argument is excessive and user-unfriendly due to increased cost and memory footprint.  Concatenation of n-element and m-element array is expected to have memory footprint of `n+m` elements , not `n+2*m`.